# Text won't start in the top left of Text Box

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have an input description box with a fixed height and width and its own style. The text is centred but I want it to start in the top left.

HTML

```
<input id="eventDescriptionInput" placeholder="Description" />
```

CSS

```
#eventDescriptionInput {
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 25px;
border-radius: 3px;
outline: none;
border: none;[enter image description here][1]
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to continue using `input` instead of `textarea` you want to remove `height: 200px;` and add `padding-bottom: <number>px`:

```css
#eventDescriptionInput {
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 25px;
border-radius: 3px;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px gray;
padding-bottom: 200px; /* new line */
}
```

Though I would recommend using `textarea` as mentioned by someone else

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you only wanted it to be done with input tag or any other tag is acceptable as long as the style is remained.

I would suggest to use  to make things more simple.

```css
#eventDescriptionInput {
padding: 10px;
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
box-sizing: border-box;
margin-bottom: 25px;
border-radius: 3px;
outline: none;
border: none;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px gray;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="eventDescriptionInput" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```